# Serialze class as single attribute-less element with its content set to one property

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, serializable

I want to serialize/deserialize the following types:

```
// The "NameEntity" element shouldn't appear in the XML
public class NameEntity
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("names")]
public class Names : List<NameEntity>
{
}
```

I want the serialized XML to match the following scheme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<names>
  <name>Charlie</name>
  <name>Robert</name>
  <name>Nick</name>
</names>
```

In fact, the output XML is:

```
<names>
  <NameEntity>
    <name>Charlie</name>
  </NameEntity>
  ...
</names>
```

Is this possible with one of the XML attributes in .NET or I'll have to implement `IXmlSerializable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mixture of the [XmlType Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) and the [XmlText Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) like so...

```
// The "NameEntity" element shouldn't appear in the XML
[XmlType("name")]
public class NameEntity
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("names")]
public class Names : List<NameEntity>
{
}

public class SO
{
    [Test]
    public void NameEntitySerialization()
    {
        var name = new NameEntity() { Name = "Austin" };

        var serialized = <YOUR SERIALIZATION CODE HERE>
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        Assert.AreEqual("<name>Austin</name>", serialized);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ListSerialization()
    {
        var names = new Names();
        names.Add(new NameEntity() {Name = "Austin"});

        var serialized = <YOUR SERIALIZATION CODE HERE>
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        Assert.AreEqual("<names>\r\n  <name>Austin</name>\r\n</names>",
          serialized);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shimmy: Did you add the `[XmlText]` attribute as well.  Those tests passed... (it would've been foolish to post failing tests)

Comment: MY BAD sorry :'( I did decorate the `Name` property with `XmlText` att. but I forgot to remove `XmlElement` from before which still remained there (there are a bunch of other validation attribute and others and I didn't notice it)... Thank you!